# How to install Web Application Stress Tool (WAST) (homer) on Windows 7

Tags: windows, webapplicationstresstool

Since Microsoft is no longer supporting one of the most useful tools ever, apparently we are left to fend for ourselves.  Has anyone been able to get the Web Application Stress Tool (WAST) to install on their Windows 7 machine?

I found this link (albeit in Italian) to download the Homer setup program:

http://www.maurodalfreddo.it/archives/89/web-application-stress-tool-anche-su-xp

Comment: Turns out that Homer will complain about a missing file: "msvcp50.dll" on launch.  On my Windows 7 machine, this file existed in my c:\windows\system32 directory.  I copied the file in my "c:\windows\SysWOW64 directory and re-installed homer and then it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Team System (VSTS) is better option.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182561(v=vs.90)

Comment: Not sure that's a valid answer to the question asked